# IEEE Reviewer Comment Abbreviations

Tags: peer-review, journals, ieee

In the reviewer comments of an IEEE journal, I noticed that the comments were preceded by a two-letter abbreviation such as OP, MA, MI, etc. What do these abbreviations stand for?

Can you point me to the IEEE document/link where these abbreviations are explained? Thanks.

Comment: Can you anonymize an example?

Comment: Example: MA: In situation X, why is the disturbance magnitude Y? What is its relationship to a practical situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never seen those abbreviations in a review or in any of the IEEE guidelines I looked at. I suspect those are either specific to a certain journal or—more probably—of the reviewer's personal style. I'd guess that the reviewer wanted to grade their remarks and requests of amendments and the meaning could be as follows:

- MA(JOR)
- MI(NOR)
- OP(TIONAL)

If the above doesn't fit and you think those labels may influence your revision in a significant way, contact the editor for clarification.

Comment: That actually makes sense! I had a hard time googling it.